# If the server is busy what happened to AsyncTask class?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, server, timedelay

My app is using AsyncTask using the getData method and is calling the Server and show the results inside a gridview.
I think about the top point Visit .

what happen to AsyncTask if the process waits much longer?
  And how do I Control it in this Circumstance?
  If it can not be controlled with AsyncTask , is there any other way(other class)?
   is this new class the Same(like) these Methods ( onPost(),onPre(),doInBack(),...) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally like to have a timeout time for an AsyncTask using a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) with [postDelayed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) to handle closing an AsyncTask if it takes to long and let the user know it has run for too long, or if internet connection is out.

Exmaple:

```
public static void performCountdown(final AsyncTask task, final Context ctx){

    //If network access is not possible, cancel task.
    if(!checkNetworkStatus(ctx)){
        task.cancel(true);            
    }else {

        //Run a handler thread to timeout a query if it takes too long.
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Task has taken longer then 15 seconds
                task.cancel(true);
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 15000);
    }
}
```

And you could call this performCountdown in your onPreExecute() for the AsyncTask. I suggest at each task.cancel(true) call using a callback or creating a Toast for the user, but I'll leave that bit up to you. Also MAKE SURE you add this to the task's onPostExecute()

```
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

This will cancel the handler so that it doesn't try to cancel your task if it successfully executes.

Which requires having a reference to the handler you called in onPreExexcute(). Which you could handle by having a class that extends AsyncTask and can maintain reference / these method calls.

```
/**
 * Check the network's state on the current device.
 */
public static boolean checkNetworkStatus(Context ctx){
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(info == null) return false;
    if(info.isRoaming()) return false;
    return info != null && info.isConnected();
}
```

Comment: Accept the answer so others will know it worked if you found this answer to work for you :)